# Groovy Transform json nested Structure to jsonobject from array

Tags: groovy, jsonbuilder

the input is

```
{
  "Id": ["A1", "A2", "A3"],
  "isAvailable": true,
  "isActive": true
}
```

the output should be like

```
{
  "Id": "A1",
  "isAvailable": true,
  "isActive": true
},

{
  "Id": "A2",
  "isAvailable": true,
  "isActive": true
},

{
  "Id": "A3",
  "isAvailable": true,
  "isActive": true
}
```

i tried following code but struck please help i tried  json builder but not working

```
    def input = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputfile);
    for (int i = 0; i < id.size(); i++){
     def output = {
                    id: id[i]
                    isAvailable:  input.isAvailable
                    isActive: input.isActive      
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple collect would do:

```
import groovy.json.*

def input = new JsonSlurper().parseText '{"Id": ["A1", "A2", "A3"],"isAvailable": true,"isActive": true }'

def result = input.Id.collect{ input + [ Id:it ] }

assert JsonOutput.prettyPrint( JsonOutput.toJson( result ) ) == '''\
[
    {
        "Id": "A1",
        "isAvailable": true,
        "isActive": true
    },
    {
        "Id": "A2",
        "isAvailable": true,
        "isActive": true
    },
    {
        "Id": "A3",
        "isAvailable": true,
        "isActive": true
    }
]'''
```